# Real parents vs biological parents

Tags: vocabulary

I've heard that the phrase 'real parent(s)' doesn't mean 'biological parent(s)', because (according to what I've heard) it is used for those parents who have adopted a child. However, people usually use these two interchangeably.

Are these two phrases the same or different?

Comment: There is no official definition of the term. "Real" just means "real." Some  people think of biology as the primary defining feature of a parent. Other people find it insulting to imply that the people who raised a child are *not*  the "real" parents.

Comment: 'real' is more often used to mean 'biological'.

Comment: I agree with @Mitch.  If - without any other context - someone were to refer to their "real parents", I would initially think they were referring to their biological parents.  Hence you need to be make the intended meaning clear in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Real" isn't specific so it can mean (almost) whatever the speaker wants. If someone has never had a good relationship with their biological parents, they may use "real parents" to refer to the people who brought them up. Conversely children who know they were adopted may want to find their "real" - as in biological - parents.

This means that using "real parents" in reference to someone else's family is a bad idea unless they have made the meaning clear to you.